# how to animate transition from right to left on Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to animate the transition when a card is activate on a Panel. any idea please?

The main.setActiveItem(1) is changing the card but I want to animate the transition from right to left (not the default from left to right)

I have this function:

```
buttonBackImageDetalle: function(button, e, options) {

    var main = this.getMain();
    //Ext.fx.Animation.setDirection('right');
    main.setActiveItem(1);
    console.log('<-- back');

}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

`main.animateActiveItem(1, {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'})`

Comment: This is not working for me. I dont pass index, rather I pass the object itself

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using controller use ref for main and pass xtype of view as follows.

```
this.getMain().animateActiveItem(your_xtype, {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'});
```