# How to add sliding efffect in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need to show views with a sliding effect in sencha touch 2. What method should be used?
I am using
either

Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').setActiveItem('secondview');

or

```
Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').animateActiveItem(1, {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'}); 
Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').add('categorylist');
```

But in some cases, sliding effect is not rendered. Under what all 
conditions are the sliding effect effected? Any configs that are compulsory for views?

The mainpanel code   have an view xtype 'carouselcontainer', the code of which is displayed below

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.CarouselContainer",{
    extend     : 'Ext.Panel',
    id         : 'carouselcontainer',
    xtype      : 'carouselcontainer',
    requires   : [
                  'Ext.Carousel','Ext.data.Store','Ext.dataview.List'
                  ],
    config      :{
        layout  :'card',
        items   :[{

                xtype : 'carousel',
                id:'car1',
                animation: {
                    type: 'slide',
                    direction: 'left'
                },

                listeners:{

                    initialize : function() {
                         Ext.Ajax.request({
                         url: url_host+'GetCategory?rest_id='+rest_id,
                         success: function(response, opts) {
                         var h = Math.ceil(Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight() * 0.7);
                         var padvalue=h*.2;
                         var padvalue2=h/8.5;
                         var w = Math.ceil(Ext.Viewport.getWindowWidth() * 0.9);

                         obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                         lengthArray=obj.category.length;
                         console.log('lengthArray'+lengthArray);
                         var division=Math.floor(lengthArray/num1);
                         console.log('division'+division);
                         var modulus=lengthArray%num1;
                         console.log('modulus'+modulus);
                         if(modulus>0) {
                             var pages=division+1;
                         }else {
                              var pages=division;
                         }


                    start='';

                    console.log(pages);

                          for ( i=0;i<pages;i++)
                      {
                              t= new Date().getTime();

                              if(i==0)
                              {
                                  start=0; 
                              } 
                              else
                              {
                                  start=(i*num1)-1;   
                              }

                                str=Ext.create("MyApp.store.HomePage");

                                str.getProxy().setExtraParam('rest_id',rest_id);
                                str.getProxy().setExtraParam('start1',start);
                                str.getProxy().setExtraParam('end',num1);
                                str.getProxy().setExtraParam('t',t);



                          Ext.getCmp('car1').add([


                                                   {
                                                        xtype: 'dataview',
                                                        //id:'li'+start,
                                                        scroll: false,
                                                        scrollable : {
                                                          direction     : false,
                                                          directionLock : true
                                                        },
                                                        items:[ 

                                                        ],
                                                        listeners: {
                                                            itemtap:function(item, num, record, ev, e, eOpts) {



                                                                if(ev.data.category_name=='contact us') {


                                                                    Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').setActiveItem('contactcontainer');
                                                                    Ext.getCmp('contactcontainer').setActiveItem(2);
                                                                }
                                                                else if(ev.data.category_name=='Get Social')
                                                                    {
                                                                    Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').setActiveItem('contactcontainer');
                                                                    Ext.getCmp('contactcontainer').setActiveItem(1);
                                                                    }
                                                                else
                                                                    {
                                                                    //console.log(Ext.getCmp('categorylist').getStore());


                                                                    Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').animateActiveItem(1, {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'});
                                                                Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').add('categorylist');
                                                                    /*Ext.getCmp('categorylist').getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam('type',ev.data.client_category_id);*/
                                                                    Ext.getCmp('categorylist').getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam('cat_id',ev.data.client_category_id);
                                                                    Ext.getCmp('categorylist').getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam('rest_id',rest_id);
                                                                    Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').setActiveItem('categorylist');
                                                                    Ext.getCmp('categorylist').setActiveItem(0);
                                                                    Ext.getCmp('categorylist').getStore().load();
                                                                    //Ext.getCmp('categorylist').refresh();

                                                                //  console.log(Ext.getCmp('categorylist').getStore().url);

                                                                    }


                                                        }

                                                        },
                                                        store:str,
                                                        itemTpl: '<div id="{client_category_id}" style="margin-top:'+padvalue+'px;  float:left;text-align:center;display:block;width:49%;height:'+padvalue2+'px"><img src="{image}" /><!--<h2>{client_category_id}</h2>--!><p>{category_name}</p></div>' 

                                                    }
                                               ]);

                         str.load();

                      }
                   },
                   failure: function(response, opts) {
                      console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                   }
                });


            }

                    }

                }]
        }
});
```

The code of mainpanel is

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video'
    ],
    config: {
        id : 'mainpanel',
        layout : 'card',
        items : [
                 {
                     xtype : 'maintabpanel'
                 },
                 {
                     xtype:'contactcontainer'
                 } ,
                 {
                    xtype : 'categorylist'
                 },
                 {
                        xtype : 'categorylistsecond'
                     } 
                 ],


});
```

and that of maintabpanel is

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.MainTab", {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],
    xtype : 'maintabpanel',
    id : 'maintabpanel',
    config: {

                    id : 'home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    scrollable: false,
                    layout:'fit',
                    items: [
                            {
                        xtype:'panel',
                        id:'home_panel',
                        layout:'card',
                        items:[{
                                    xtype      : 'homeview'
                               },
                               ]
                            }
                        ]

            }
});
```

and that of 'homeview' is

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.Home",{
    extend     : 'Ext.Panel',
    id         : 'homeview',
    xtype      : 'homeview',
    requires   : [
                  'Ext.TitleBar',
                  'Ext.SegmentedButton',
                  'Ext.dataview.List',
                  'Ext.data.Store',
                  'Ext.field.Select'],
    config      :{
    layout  :'fit',
    items   :[{

            xtype : 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',  
                  //style :'background:url(resources/images/home-logo.png) no-repeat left;',
                  title:"Welcome"
            //flex  :.75//changed

            },
            {
                xtype:'carouselcontainer'
            }]
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to animate transition from right to left on Sencha Touch 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323083/how-to-animate-transition-from-right-to-left-on-sencha-touch-2)

Comment: Could you add the code of the mainpanel please.

Comment: You added the code of carouselcontainer, not mainpanel..

Answer (score 1):

you need to add in your mainpanel

```
layout: {
            type: 'card',
            animation: {
                type: 'slide',
                direction: 'left'
            }
        }
```

or

```
panel.animateActiveItem(1, {type:'slide', direction:'left'});
```

will also work

Comment: then sliding is working, but your new page code is wrong some where. if you can add you code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`animateActiveItem`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-animateActiveItem)

The first param is either the index of the view in your card layout, or a reference to this view. The second param is the animation.

Here's an example :

```
Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').animateActiveItem(1, {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: then may be the way you have added view to mainpanel is incorrect

Comment: @TDeBailleul -- direction: 'down' isn't working for me, any idea why?